# In python, is it better to loop and pop(0) or reverse it first and then pop()

Tags: python

In my code, I have two options:

One is to:

```
images = [...]
images.reverse()
while len(images) > 0:
    image = images.pop()
    # do something with the image based on timestamp
```

The other is:

```
images = [...]
while len(images) > 0:
    image = images.pop(0)
    # do something with the image based on timestamp
```

Both should work. But I am wondering from efficiency perspective, which approach is better?

#### Edit

I feel like I am not making this question clear. So I will paste more code here. The thing I need to do is something like below:

```
def __init__(self, position, tantType=True):
    self.image = self.images.pop(0)
    timer.add(interval, lambda :self.update(), len(self.images) + 1)

def update(self):
    if len(self.images) > 0:
        self.image = self.images.pop()
    else:
        self.active = False
```

So it actually poped in a timer. I feel like I can't just handle that in a loop

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If there is some processing then you're making a queue (as opposed to just trying to empty the list)?

Comment: @roganjosh I am using the images in the order based on the timestamp to display the images in order. Just for the question itself I have not mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Adding extra operations like reverse() would probably slow the process. In your case as you just remove the first element in a loop, images.pop(0) is probably faster. Or just images = []. Do not forget you can time your code if you want real timing of operations in your code to check and decide what is best in your specific case.

Comment: I think You have misunderstood what `pop` does, it removes an item from list.

Comment: You can look into [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) but it's unlikely that this is any kind of concern when you're doing image processing because that will vastly dominate the runtime over popping from a list

Comment: If You want to interact with items in list use `for var_name in list_name:`. It will loop over each item in list and You can access it with the var_name. I am pretty far in my assumptions so I will say that You have to learn more about lists and for loops

Comment: Do you actually need to empty the list at all? If not, the pops and possible resizes are pointless.

Comment: @Matiiss it removes it _and returns it_. The use of `pop` here doesn't suggest a misunderstanding if they want to gradually reduce a queue

Comment: @roganjosh well that is something I did not know till now (I should learn more about lists I guess)

Comment: @roganjosh I have made the edit to show how the whole code looks like. It is poped by a timer interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeatedly removing items from the beginning of the list is particularly bad because all the remaining items have to be shifted by one position to the left, making this an overall O(n²) operation.

The workaround of reversing the list first is better, but still unnecessary, because you can just iterate over the list.

Simply use a `for` loop, and if you need to, delete the contents of the list afterwards:

```
for image in images:
    # do something with image

images.clear()
```

To iterate over the list one step at a time in one function call, you can convert the list to an iterator at the beginning, and then use the `next()` function to advance the iteration. If the iterator is exhausted it will raise a `StopIteration` exception:

```
def __init__(self, position, tantType=True):
    self.images = iter(images)
    self.image = next(self.images)
    timer.add(interval, lambda: self.update(), len(images) + 1)

def update(self):
    try:
        self.image = next(self.images)
    except StopIteration:
        self.active = False
```

Comment: Instead of reversing the list, he can just reverse the index. i.e `for img in images[::-1]`